# unnecessary constraint in optimization problem

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, convex-optimization, linear-programming, constraints

I have some optimization problem (optimizing parameter $\alpha$)with those constraints:
$$\alpha_i\ge0$$
$$\sum\limits_i \alpha_i y_i =0$$
and a third constraints:
$$w-\sum\limits_i \alpha_i y_i x_i = 0$$

It was mentioned that the third constraint is unnecessary because any $\alpha$ would satisfy it. I can't immediately see this. Any insight?

Comment: You certainly cannot say that without further information about $x$ and $w$. Are they variables, or constants? Do you know their values, or perhaps do they fall in a certain range?

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on the values of $x_i$ and $y_i$. In general, the third constraint is most surely *not* unnecesary. For example, if $w$ is an all zero vector, and $y_1=-1$, $y_2=1$ and $x_1=0, x_2=1$, then the equations are:

$$-\alpha_1 + \alpha_2 = 0\\
-\alpha_2 = 0
$$
which has only $\alpha_1=\alpha_2=0$ as a solution. Without the third constraint, any pair $\alpha,\alpha$ is a solution if $\alpha\geq0$

Comment: Why is it almost sure unnecessary?

Comment: @MAS I edited my question with an example in which the third constraint changes the results.